# Sequel many_to_one association failing with "Conversion failed" when using an alphanumeric key

Tags: ruby, sql-server, sequel, tiny-tds

I'm working with an existing MSSQL database to which I have little to no control over as it's a legacy application built by others.  I'm attempting to associate two tables in a one_to_many association.

Here's the code snippet which defines the association:

```
class RollHistory < Sequel::Model :rollhst
  many_to_one :roll_inventory, :key => :roll_num
end

class RollInventory < Sequel::Model :rollinventory
  one_to_many :roll_history, :key => :roll_num
end
```

Note:  Both these classes work as expected without the association...

```
pry(main)> DB.roll_history.where(:roll_num => 'ZB30217').first
=> #<RollHistory @values={:seqnum=>1054318, :status=>"D", :del_date=>"20081120", :date_rcvd=>"20081120", :inv_num=>"CG868489", :line_num=>1, :roll_num=>"ZB30217", :job_name=>"CHATEAU MONTAGNE", :cust_name=>"CHATEAU MONTAGNE", :amt_used=>92.5, :beg_length=>123.25, :custlineseqnum=>0, :deltktdate=>"        ", :remarks=>"", :trans_date=>"20111027", :grs_cost=>1.75, :adjustmentid=>0}>

pry(main)> DB.roll_inventory.where(:roll_num => 'ZB30217').first
=> #<RollInventory @values={:pr_code=>"01", :manf=>"SPECIAL ORDER", :supplier=>"SHAW INDUSTRIES, INC", :style_num=>"50249", :style=>"WINCHESTER 26 OZ", :colornum=>"", :color=>"YORK BLUE", :backing=>0, :notused_1=>"  ", :roll_num=>"ZB30217", :dye_lot=>"80721", :quality=>1, :width=>12.0, :beg_length=>123.25, :amt_used=>97.25, :amt_resv=>0.0, :amt_avail=>26.0, :grs_cost=>0.5, :net_cost=>0.5, :freight=>0.0, :frt_code=>"", :inv_date=>"20081113", :sidemark=>"DS/CHATEAU MONTAGNE", :date_rcvd=>"20081113", :inv_num=>"2210643", :roll_cut=>"R", :fibertype=>2, :styletype=>0, :notused_2=>"   ", :location=>"", :privlabelco=>"SHAW INDUSTRIES, INC", :ponumber=>"#ST175780003", :softreserve=>0, :unit_price=>0.0, :colortype=>0, :weight=>0.0, :pile=>0.0, :toxicitynum=>"", :load=>0.0, :comments=>"REF.#365109", :store=>32, :seqnum=>4646, :stock=>0, :errm=>0, :serialno=>"", :pricelistseqnum=>0, :colorseqnum=>0, :source=>" ", :ap_voided=>0, :userreal1=>0.0, :insertedby=>"Not Known", :inserteddatetime=>nil, :lastchangedby=>"WS101:jpereira", :lastchangeddatetime=>2012-10-17 13:00:08 -0400, :trans_date=>nil, :useextendedhistory=>0, :collection=>"", :privcollection=>""}>
```

However, here's the output I get when trying to use the association:

```
pry(main)> DB.roll_history.where(:roll_num => 'ZB30217').first.roll_inventory
Sequel::DatabaseError: TinyTds::Error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ZB30217' to data type int.
from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.7.0/lib/sequel/adapters/tinytds.rb:233:in `fields'

pry(main)> DB.roll_inventory.where(:roll_num => 'ZB30217').first.roll_history
Sequel::DatabaseError: TinyTds::Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '#10665277' to data type int.
from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.7.0/lib/sequel/adapters/tinytds.rb:233:in `fields'
```

I'm not sure what `#10665277` represents as I get the same number no matter which `roll_num` I use, so I suspect that's a key to solving this, but for now I'm at a loss.

Am I doing something wrong when defining my associations because the key is alphanumeric?  I couldn't find anything in the SEQUEL docs on this.

Clearly, I could simply gather all the records from `roll_history` with the proper `roll_num` and, indeed, that's what I'm doing now... but I'de like to figure out why the association doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the SQL generated (add a Database logger in Sequel to see the SQL) or any details about the schema, so I can only guess that the primary key values for the rollhst and rollinventory tables are integers and not strings. You probably need to set the :primary_key option on the associations to reference `roll_num`: `:primary_key=>:roll_num`.